# How can I disable the rubber band effect of the Preview program?

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

According to other sources, I've disabled the `NSScrollViewRubberbanding` system option, and it works in my browsers and other softwares. But it doesn't work for the Preview program, specifically when I read the PDF files. How can I disable the effect for the Preview too?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible for apps such as Preview which use a different scroll view.

You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- http://apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Comment: Send the feedback. Does that mean it's impossible to do this by now?